# Tesseract OCR 3.0 + dll C#

Tags: compiler-errors, tesseract

I found the sample project on google and downloaded that and compiled the sample .net project.

1. Is there a location for where I can find a populated tessdata folder or do I have to train the library? As I am evaluating, would prefer if I can find a pre-populated tessdata folder for english.
2. The sample project did open my sample jpeg file, however it did not auto rotate. I assume this may be becuase of no files in tessdata folder. Is this a correct assumption or is tesseract dll supposed to perform auto rotate on loading the image
3. I tried opening a gray scale image and it failed stating that the pixel is not supported. I couldn't locate any documentation that listed such a restriction. Can anyone help me verify this?
4. Basically I am looking to auto rotate documents that come via fax/scan etc - so if there is another open source alternative that I can use in a C# project, I am open to that idea as well.

UPDATE 1:
I got this down
[tesseract on google](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.01-1.exe&can=2&q=)

Launched cmd prompt and launched tesseract.exe with follwowing

```
>tesseract.exe myimage.tiff -l eng
```

got the following error

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, TIFFstream: unknown field with tag 59932 (0xea1c) en
countered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, TIFFstream: unknown field with tag 59932 (0xea1c) en
countered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, TIFFstream: unknown field with tag 59932 (0xea1c) en
countered.
Page 0
```

UPDATE 2:
sorted out issue on the errors, however auto rotate does not seem to be happeneing automatically

Comment: there is another c# tesseract wrapper that it worth checking out. It worked like a charm in my case and its way more elegant https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract